# Count Down Timer For Entire Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, countdowntimer

Am having multiple activity For example say N number of activities
When an activity starts the countdown timer begins
Here my question?
After the countdown timer starts I want to switch over to another activity.so that time the count down timer should be resume when the activity changed to another ....
Can any one give me the answer with suitable example
Thanks in advance

Comment: when a activity starts the countdown timer begin this only I tried so far

Answer (score 1):

Send the starting time of the timer to another activity via an intent. So:

```
long timerStarted = System.currentTimeMillis();

Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("timerStarted", timerStarted);
```

Then in the next activity use

```
getIntent().getLongExtra("timerStarted", System.currentTimeMillis());
```

You will keep the timer consistent with its start time in the previous activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same code as used in splashScreen.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            /*
             * Showing splash screen with a timer.
             */

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                Intent i = new Intent(Act1.this, Act2.class);
                startActivity(i);
                // close this activity
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
```